# You are not authorized to view this page

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, iis-7, web-config

I am getting the following error while browsing the my webpage

i checked and seen anaymous access has been enabled and integrated aunthentication has been turned off ...

Could you please help?

```
You are not authorized to view this page


You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Please try the following:

Contact the Web site administrator if you believe you should be able to view this directory or page. 
Click the Refresh button to try again with different credentials. 
HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
Internet Information Services (IIS)


Open in New WindowSelect All
Tags: 
Add Tags
    Add Tags

Zones: 
Microsoft IIS Web Server, .Net Application Servers, Programming for
```

My web.conf look like below:

```
<!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also check the NTFS permissions on the directory and files in your web site itself.  The easiest way to determine if this is the problem is by giving Everyone READ access.  Test it.  Then remove the Everyone entry.  If that had solved the problem, find out what user account the IIS application pool hosting your web app uses, and add that user account to the NTFS permissions list giving that user Read access.